# How to disable a button after clicking it in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

This might be a simple question.but,does any one know how to disable a button after clicking it in OpenERP?
Please help!!!!!
Thanks for all your help....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways to hide the button in view.

1. Change the state of the object and display button on the bases of the stat.

e.g

```
<button name="invoice_open" states="draft,proforma2" string="Approve" icon="terp-camera_test"/>
```

This the example of [`account.invoice`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/head:/account/account_invoice_view.xml) where `Approve` button will be visible if the `invoice` is in `draft` or `proforma2` state.

1. You can add `group` to view and button will be display for that `groups` only.

e.g

```
<field name="account_id" groups="account.group_account_user"/>
```

This is the example of `account.invoice.line` where the `account_id` field is shown to the only those user who are belongs to `account.group_account_user`.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If we talking about web interface then you could disable it by javascript.

Answer (score -2):

If you are talking about Web Interface, Yes It's possible using Javascript.

```
$('button').click(function(){$(this).prop('disabled', true);});
```

Comment: where would you put the javascript though?